# Could not find a base address. WCF baseAddress is not working

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm trying to fix the error of `baseAddress`.

When I try to instantiate the service host in my MVC controller, it throws an exception.

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

This is my simple c# code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF_Example.Service1));
    host.Open();

    return View();
}
```

Config:

```
<service name="WCF_Example.Service1"  behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:61940/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint 
        address="WCF_ServiceExample" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        contract="WCF_Example.IService1" />
    <endpoint 
        address="mex" 
        binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to run the service outside of Visual Studio? The base address in your config looks like the address VS uses when running from within the IDE. It won't work outside the IDE (unless you have created a web server with that exact port).

Comment: No is everything is working in the same solution